# python hidapi: Windows vs Mac

Tags: python-3.x, usb, hid, libusb

I've written Python code to communicate to the [Microchip MCP2210](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP2210) and the [MCP2221A](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP2221A) USB / HID chips.  I'm using hidapi (0.9.0.post3) for low-level communication.

Both devices expect a 64 byte request packet and reply with a 64 byte response.

But I stumbled upon a difference when running under MacOS vs Windows 10.  Specifically, under windows, I need to pad the request packet with a leading zero byte:

```
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            cmd_pkt = [0x0] + cmd_pkt
```

This approach seems to work, but I'd rest easier if I knew why this is required.

Can someone explain?  And is there a more robust approach?

Comment: can you tell, what error message you see (your though process...), what sort of packet does it happens on? if it happens for all can you describe one of your cases? I'm far from being expert in that domain, but I'm willing to help could it be the report number ?
```c
https://github.com/libusb/hidapi/blob/master/README.md:126 // Request state (cmd 0x81). The first byte is the report number (0x0).
```

Comment: @Zoyolin: yes, I suspect the leading 0 byte is the report number.  What I don't know is why the Windows hidapi requires it and why the Mac and Linux version doesn't.